# How do I write a converting (lowercase->uppercase, single digits->double its value, two digits->sum of its digits) program w/ letters & numbers?

Tags: java

I was tasked to write a function that takes in user input as a string. For all characters which are numeric, double its value and, if it is
two digits, then replace it with the sum of its digits (e.g., 6 → 12 → 3 whereas 3 → 6). For all characters which are in uppercase, replace it with lowercase. For all characters which are in lowercase, replace it with uppercase (e.g., m → M and N → n). The program should keep asking the user to enter strings until they either enter ‘q’ or
‘Q’ to quit.
I have this so far, which works for the conversion of the letters. I'm not sure how to implement the other part into it and where it would go.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str1;
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    str1 = scan.nextLine();
    StringBuffer newStr = new StringBuffer(str1);

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {

        //Checks for lower case character
        if (Character.isLowerCase(str1.charAt(i))) {
            //Convert it into upper case using toUpperCase() function
            newStr.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(str1.charAt(i)));
        }
        //Checks for upper case character
        else if (Character.isUpperCase(str1.charAt(i))) {
            //Convert it into upper case using toLowerCase() function
            newStr.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(str1.charAt(i)));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("String after conversion : " + newStr);
}
```

}

Comment: Since the entire input is a String, checking for digits will need to be considered before manipulating the characters

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach

```
    public static String conversion(String inputString){
        String out = "";
        for(char c:inputString.toCharArray()){
            if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c))*2;
                if(num>=10){
                    char[] parts = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
                    int sum = 0;
                    sum+=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(parts[0]));
                    sum+=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(parts[1]));
                    out+=sum;
                }else out+=num;
            }else{
                if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) out+=Character.toLowerCase(c);
                else out+=Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```